# Responsive text overlay on flexbox image gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox, image-gallery

So i have this code to display image gallery. I want to place "box-text" class on the middle of each image. But if i want use position: relative it doesn't work. Text doesn't want to go higher than the bottom of the image, no matter how I set the top property in css.

```
<div class="container">  
  <div class="box">
       <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       <div class="box-text"><h2>Some text</h2><h3>other text</h3></div>
   </div>

     <div class="box">
       <img src="2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       <div class="box-text"><h2>Some text</h2><h3>other text</h3></div>
     </div>

    <div class="box">
       <img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
       <div class="box-text"><h2>Some text</h2><h3>other text</h3></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My css styles:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
   }

.box img{
    z-index: 1;
  }


.box-text{
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use position: absolute instead? You can also use transform: translate to help with the centering:

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}
.box-text{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
}
```

Comment: Flex can also do the centering for you if you bring it onto the 'box' class that surrounds the text elements. If you do that you can lose the left and top and transform altogether and let flex do all the work.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I think he needs the text to overlay the inline image.

Comment: Yes that still works, you keep the aboslute positioning as you have it but don't specify the left and top - works in quick test in firefox for me anyway.

Comment: I also added text-align:center on the box-text class just for good measure - may not be the requirement though.

Comment: I don't know why but it moves my text not to the center, but to the right bottom corner of the picture.

Comment: But solution with bring flex into the 'box' works. Thanks.